# SDL2 not showing window in wsl2

Tags: c++, sdl-2, wsl-2

I'm using wsl2 Debian. After contemplating my life to install 245 MB of libsdl2-dev apt install, I tried `g++ sdl.cpp -lSDL2 -o sdlbasic` and I got this huge string of text, all seems to be one combined error. Then I reinstalled it, and it actually compiled the program. But when I ran ./sdlbasic, I got this error:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
The path /dev/dri/ cannot be opened or is not available
The path /dev/dri/ cannot be opened or is not available
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
The path /dev/dri/ cannot be opened or is not available
The path /dev/dri/ cannot be opened or is not available
```

I had a delay in there, too, and it actually delayed 10 seconds despite the errors. Here is my beginner's code to draw a white pixel in the middle of the screen:

```
// g++ sdl.cpp -lSDL2 -o sdlbasic

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#define swidth 640
#define sheight 480

int main(){
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(swidth, sheight, 0, &window, &renderer); // width and height
    SDL_RenderSetScale(renderer, 4, 4); // x4 render size

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255); // choose color to draw, rgba
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255); // white
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, swidth/2, sheight/2); // draw pixel in center

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); // show renderer stuff
    SDL_Delay(10000); // delay until close
    return 0;
}
```

**I tried**

1. re-compiling the program
2. following this stack exchange tutorial, but I don't know what Nautilus is
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/456689/error-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-in-the-environment-when-attempting-to-run-naut

Comment: Did the tutorial not explain how to set up the display server?

Comment: @sweenish This is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOXg1ImX5j0&list=PLYmIsLVSssdIOn5J71CVBblPlXici1_2A&ab_channel=TheBuilder
It's very simple, and assumes you already know how to install sdl and the display server.

Comment: Seems you need a different tutorial.

Comment: you could just compile it on windows with msys2 or msvc, you don't need to complicate things with a container, and if you need to compile a linux binary you can just use a VM, the main problem of containers is that hardware acceleration is almost impossible.

Comment: WSL2 is a VM, with hardware acceleration.

Comment: If you've solved your issue, answer your question with the solution, don't edit the question. This isn't a forum.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my error by updating the latest version of WSL2, which has built-in Linux GUI capabilities. (How lucky.) To see more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps